# Get class from <body> tag within HTML string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I have a string of HTML like this

```
var html = "<html><head></head><body class='getMe'></body></html>";
```

I want to get the body tags class and I tried doing that like this.

```
$(html).filter("body").attr("class") 

$(html).find("body").attr("class");
```

But both methods return undefined. Any help?

Comment: Is the html forced to be a string in a variable or is it parsed by browser as just html?

Comment: The problem is that `$(html)` is returning an empty jQuery object. You can only use this to parse elements that can be incorporated into the document body, it ignores elements like `<html>` and `<head>` and `<body>`.

Comment: Actually, that's browser-dependent. It uses the browser's internal `innerHTML` parser.

Comment: So is there a solution? Is there not a way of getting the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to parse into html, rather try RegExp:

```
var html = "<html><head></head><body class='getMe'></body></html>";
var clazz = html.match(/body\sclass=['|"]([^'|"]*)['|"]/)[1]; //getMe
```

Here, `String.match()` gives array of string for given pattern.
`body\sclass=['|"]([^'|"]*)['|"]` gives `["body class='getMe'", "getMe"]`. Using `()`, you can grab a particular group.

Also works with multiple classes and other attributes:

```
var html = "<html><head></head><body class='getMe hey there' id='xyz' bgcolor='red'></body></html>";
var clazz = html.match(/body\sclass=['|"]([^'|"]*)['|"]/)[1]; //getMe hey there
```

*Edited*

In order to get classes belonging to body tag starting with `header-`:

```
var html = "<html><head></head><body class='getMe header header-1 header-two test'></body></html>";
var headers = html.match(/body\sclass=['|"]([^'|"]*)['|"]/)[1].match(/(header\-\w+)/g);
//["header-1", "header-two"]
```

Comment: This works well, although what if I want to get a specific class that begins with "header-", your code gets all classes in the body tag. I only  want a class that starts with "header-".

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
var html = "<html><head></head><body class='getMe'></body></html>";
var className = $("<html />", {"html":html}).find("body")[0].className;
console.log(className);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

Did you try to put it in a Variable? find the tag without ""

```
var MyClass = $(body).attr("class");

// or $(html).find(body).attr("class");
```

Comment: `$(body)` is the body of the current document, not the HTML string.

Comment: exactly. He wants to get the class name that is attached to <body>.

But enlighten me, I may have the question wrong.

Comment: But it's not the body of the document, it's the body of a random piece of HTML in a string variable.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure your code will even work. There's no variable `body`.

Comment: Hmm, I may try that at home. Any suggestions before I test?